# Capture objects which are pops up from web page - Automation Anywhere

Tags: automation, automationanywhere

I just need to click on "OK" , the pop up generated by web page , i m not able to perform click operation on pop-up generated by web page in Automation Anywhere

[image: Screenshot]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex63s.png)

Comment: I just need to click on "OK" , the pop up generated by web page ,  i m not able to perform click operation on pop-up generated by web page in Automation Anywhere.

Comment: After which action does the popup come?

Comment: i will click on select ALL and i will click on create posting file , it will show the labels then i will click on create posting file for ALL then i will get pop up message

Comment: i used Activate windows title message from webpage even before performing click operation still not working , i used if object properties exist perform click operation , i used image recognition then performed insert mouse click still no use ..

Comment: Are you sure that your code isn't waiting for the pop-up to dismiss and then moving to next instruction after click? additionally if the object is recognized in Object cloning, then the mouse should move on the OK button on that step, is it happening?

Comment: After getting POP-UP if i perform manual click on "OK" it is going for next in Automation Script program , but i want that manual click to be automated i tried with different approach but i m not getting the result .

Comment: I tried using If Object Properties (Message from web page) then perform click operation , i tried with currently Active window , i tried using image recognition (message from web page) then insert key stroke - Enter ,

before performing click operation i activate window title (message from server ) but no result .

Comment: 1. Try SMART recorder option to capture the complete workflow and check how the pop-up window is captured in that.   <br/>  2. Try Record option from Workbench/Task Editor to capture the pop-up window and check on that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the object Cloning command works on that type of windows, you just need to put the main window of the object cloning as "Message from webpage" instead of the main webpage.

If not Image recognition shpuld work perfectly

Answer (score -1):

You can use selenium. use find_by to locate the popup element.

```
close_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("popover-x-button-close")[0]
close_button.click()
sum_div.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
```

Comment: I recommend using this in try catch block.

Comment: sir i m performing click operation in web page using RPA- Automation Anywhere ,

Comment: @Ahmed The OP clearly mentioned his issue is related to AA.